# Python - Insert data into a word document using a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-docx

I have a word document with data and I have 2 lists with phrases. I would like to loop through the word document and wherever a specific keyword is found (so keyword_one and keyword_two in this instance), add a new line and insert the first item from the relevant list.

My code below is only adding one item from one list to keyword_one and I think it could be to do with the for loop structure - please could someone point me in the right direction?

Code:

```
document = Document('mydocx.docx')
my_list=['Some key points here', 'We expected values to be higher. That is fine', 'final attributes', 'local dataset'] 
my_second_list=['My random data', 'Flowers. That is fine', 'happy birthday', 'puppies']

for para in document.paragraphs:
    print(para.text)
    for i in my_list:
        for j in my_second_list:
            if 'Keyword_one' in para.text: 
                para.add_run('         ' +i)
            if 'Keyword_two' in para.text:
                para.add_run('      ' + j)
        else:
            break
            
document.save("mydocx.docx")
```

Desired example output:

```
My ms word document.

Keyword_one
Some key points here. I have some additional data
Other data here

Keyword_two 
Flowers

Heading 1

Keyword_one
We expected values to be higherThat is fine'

Keyword_one 
final attributes

Keyword_two 
My random data. Other random data here

Heading 1

Keyword_two 
Flowers
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean when the first keyword shows up, insert the first item of the first list (and same for second keyword) - and the next time the first keyword shows up again, use the second item of the first list, etc.? What is supposed to happen when you have gone through the entire list?

Comment: That's correct. It can just stop once it reaches the last element of both lists regardless of if there are more instances in the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should give you the result you are looking for:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('mydocx.docx')
my_list = ['Some key points here', 'We expected values to be higher. That is fine', 'final attributes', 'local dataset'] 
my_second_list = ['My random data', 'Flowers. That is fine', 'happy birthday', 'puppies']

i = 0
j = 0
for para in document.paragraphs:
   if 'Keyword_one' in para.text and i < len(my_list):
      para.add_break()
      para.add_run(my_list[i])
      i += 1
   elif 'Keyword_two' in para.text and j < len(my_second_list):
      para.add_break()
      para.add_run(my_second_list[j])
      j += 1

document.save("mydocx.docx")
```

In the case where a paragraph contains both keywords and you want it to add from both lists, change the `elif` to `if`.